# Indexing column in KSQLDB to avoid full table scans

Tags: ksqldb, confluent-cloud

Here is a table I have:

```
CREATE TABLE PEOPLE AS
  SELECT 
    LATEST_BY_OFFSET(CITY),
    ...some irrelevant columns,
    SSN,
  FROM PEOPLE_STREAM GROUP BY SSN;
```

Queries I want to be efficient:

```
select *   from PEOPLE where SSN  = 'blah'; // very efficient as its key
select SSN from PEOPLE where CITY = 'bleh'; // full table scan
```

I tried "indexing" it using COLLECT_SET and materialized view

```
CREATE TABLE CITY_TO_PEOPLE as
  SELECT CITY, COLLECT_SET(SSN) as SSNS
  FROM PEOPLE GROUP BY CITY
```

Querying it is fast, but unfortunately there is a value size limit for COLLECT_SET which we are not able to change (Confluent Cloud is limiting it to 1000).

Is there another way to do it in ksqldb?